# Interactive calculation of object area depending on its location in the UTM zone using QGIS

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, area, wgs84, utm

I want to interactively calculate the area of a geometric object and use different projections  depending on its location.

Source data is stored in [WGS 84](https://epsg.io/4326).
The area should be calculated in the WGS 84 UTM ХХ zones (also they are different for the [south](https://epsg.io/32701) and [north](https://epsg.io/32601) pole).

**How can this be achieved using QGIS?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Interactive calculation of the object area depending on its location can be done in QGIS with the help of an [auxiliary layer](https://drive.google.com/file/d/1nps7i05h2GIC8iSAV2-VWnebw9n-w--6/view?usp=sharing), which contains UTM zones and `EPSG` column, in which for each UTM zone must be a unique EPSG identifier (examples are in the question).

[image: auxiliary layer UTM]

This code should be used to calculate the `EPSG` column (see this [answer](https://gis.stackexchange.com/a/341300/35561)). If the object is in more than one UTM zone, the expression determines which zone contains the largest portion of the object.

```
with_variable('feat',
              get_feature_by_id('UTM',
                                array_first(overlay_intersects('UTM', 
                                                               $id, 
                                                               sort_by_intersection_size:='des'
                                                               )
                                            )
                                ), 
             attribute(@feat, 'EPSG')
             )
```

This code should be used to calculate the `area` column:

```
area( 
     transform($geometry, 
               @layer_crs,
               'EPSG:' || to_string(EPSG)
               )
     )
```

**Note** that the projection of the auxiliary UTM layer and the layer in which the area is calculated must be the same.